# How to optimize Template Matching with OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection

I wrote a code for template matching in `Pythons` `OpenCV` lib.

Data is soccer players. I have created dataset for templates with more than 100 images of Lionel's Messi face.

I have read that this kind of algorithm (template matching) is sensitive to size of the template, so I wanted to fix that. This is how I wrote my code:

1 Part: I have used haarcascade to detect faces on image, and I get the size of extracted faces / image of face

2 Part: I have loaded more than 100 templates and resize them to size of detected face (1 Part)

3 Part: I have done template matching with resized templates and original image.

The problem is that my code does not perform well, it rarely finds good match.
Is there something that I can do to fix this, to make better performance?
What am I doing wrong?

You can download the dataset from here:

https://www.sendspace.com/filegroup/XxOrEtkpmRtyVkJTp22ESQ

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import random

# Read templates

data_folder = r'C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\FaceDetection'
categories = ['Messi']    
templates = []

#LOADING TEMPLATES AND CREATING LIST OF TEMPLATES
def get_templates(width, height):

    for cat in categories:

        path = os.path.join(data_folder, cat)

        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:

                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img), 0)
                img_array = cv2.resize(img_array,(int(width),int(height)))

                templates.append([img_array,cat])

            except:
                pass


# Downloading multiple cascades: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades
# loading cascades for detection

frontal_face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

# IMPORTING THE IMAGE AND CONVERTING IT TO GRAY SCALE
my_image = r'C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\FaceDetection\for_comparing.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(my_image, 1)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = frontal_face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.2, 5)

for (x,y,w,h) in faces:

    #FINDING FACES WITH RECTANGLE
    #cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0), 1)

    # GETTING SIZE OF DETECTED FACE
    face_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    face_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    #SHOWING DETECTED FACES
    #cv2.imshow('img',face_color)
    #cv2.waitKey(0)

    # SIZE OF DETECTED FACES ARE INTO VARIABLES
    height, width, c = face_color.shape

    # CALLING THE FUNCTION FOR TEMPLATES
    get_templates(width, height)
    random.shuffle(templates)

    for template in templates: # FOR EACH TEMPLATE IN TEMPLATE LIST

        w, h = template[0].shape[::-1]

        res = cv2.matchTemplate(gray, template[0], cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

        threshold = 0.90 # I HAVE TRIED VALUES FROM 0.75 TO 0.95

        # Store the coordinates of matched area in a numpy array 
        loc = np.where(res >= threshold)

#IF MATCH IS FOUND, DRAW RECTANGLE AROUND IT
        if len(loc[0]) != 0:
            print("FOUND", template[1])

            # Draw a rectangle around the matched region. 
            for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):

                rec = cv2.rectangle(img, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 1)
                cv2.putText(rec, template[1], (x, y-3), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0,0,255), 1)


cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: For me it sounds like a problem for deep learning. Did you try it? (CNN with binary classifier)

Comment: I haven't

Is it possible to do it with Scikit Learn lib?

Comment: I mean, I do not know how to make CNN, I have used regression, clustering and classification with scikit learn

I have also tried to use classification for solving this problem but I didnt succseed

Comment: [Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.06655.pdf) you have an example of face recognition by using deep learning. For CNN purpose you can use Keras framework.